# Executable doesn't run on boot-up when changed to write the logs to a file

Tags: linux, boot, services, c

I am running an executable on boot-up, and the executable prints logs via `printf` to the console and when the service runs, I see the binary running in the output of `ps` but no longers are printed to the console.

So to see the logs, I changed the application such that it creates files instead but the executable doesn't seem to run on boot-up after this change, even though the service that's supposed to run this executable is running.

Creating and writing to files works perfectly fine when run manually and not on boot-up.

1. How to enable printf logs to the console for the executable running on boot-up? I am using `dprintf` to write a file
2. Why would an executable that's supposed to create and write to a file not run on boot-up despite the service running?

Did a sample test - when there's a loop, and the executable is pushed, on boot-up it runs but as soon as the loop is commented out, the executable no longer runs.

```c
#define file1        "file1"
#define file2        "file2"
int CreateFiles()
{
    dprintf (1, "Creating files");
    int fd = open (file1, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        dprintf (1, "Failed to open the file descriptor");
        return -1;
    }

    fd = open (file2, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        dprintf (1, "Failed to open the file descriptor");
        return -1;
    }
  return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
   while(1);
   CreateFiles();
}
```

Comment: How do you start the program? Does it have permissions to access the file? Really, without knowing anything about the program, it's rather hard to say how it could fail.  If it's something you built yourself, you could make a minimal _but complete_ mock version of the program that still shows the problem. (The code you posted isn't complete, it's missing at least the implementation of `WriteToFile()`.)

Comment: Thing though is, the same file runs fine when there's a loop so I think it makes sense to rule out permission issues. Perhaps the executable is failing somewhere? (didn't fail when I run manually though). Any way you could see anything related to it?

Comment: Except if you have a permission or other issue that causes an error and the program exits after the error. Or whatever. Point is, we can't know without knowing what the program actually does and how it's started. You could possibly try to arrange it so that you can trigger the issue on demand when starting it from the command line too, that would help getting the service manager out of the picture.

Comment: Well, the binary does run fine when I don't create the files and/or write to it so again I hardly see that being the case here. It probably has to do with file creation....and to debug the potential failure, I reckon we'd need to access the logs being printed to the console which I currently don't